# how do I get curl to save a file to a specified directory?

Tags: command-line-interface, curl

I'm trying to get curl, using a script, to download a file and save it to a certain directory. I got it to download but I dont know how to get it to a certain directory from a script. It usually just saves it to the current working directory.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typical User use-case, not directly related to System Administration. Questions like this should be asked on [unix.SE]. This question is too old to migrate there.

Comment: @ChrisS This doesn't make sense to me. System administrators constantly use curl and other tools to download to a specified directory. It is a fundamental part of system administration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
curl http://google.com > /path/to/dir/index.html
```

Answer (score 10):

CORRECTION:

You can use

-o, --output FILE    Write output to instead of stdout

`curl --url https://google.com --output /any/file-location`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Documentation for -o says: >> The file will be saved in the current working directory. If you want the file saved in a different directory, make sure you change the current working directory before invoking curl with this option.

Answer (score 2):

Let curl and the shell each do what they do well:

```
(cd TARGET_DIRECTORY && curl ...)
```

Also there may be things that interest you in the description of the `-o` option in the manual.